# QT/SVG: set shape-rendering to "optimizeSpeed" with QSvgGenerator

Tags: qt, svg

I want to set the following *SVG* flag :

```
shape-rendering = "optimizeSpeed"
```

How can I achieve that using the QSvgGenerator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that you can't set that flag with the `QSvgGenerator` itself.

But you can generate *SVG* data into the *buffer*, then parse the obtained data using `QDomDocument` and set the flag for the proper element.

```
QBuffer data;
QSvgGenerator generator;
generator.setOutputDevice(&data);

// ... generate SVG ...

QDomDocument doc;
doc.setContent(data.buffer());

QDomNodeList elements = doc.elementsByTagName("svg");

// There should be just one 'svg' element.
assert(elements.count() == 1);

// Set the flag.
elements.at(0).toElement().setAttribute("shape-rendering", "optimizeSpeed");

// Obtain SVG data as a string.
QString svg = doc.toString();
```

Comment: in line 3 shouldn't it be: generator.setOutputDevice(&data);? And thanks for the answer.